# C# DateTime Field not formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have read numerous help text and tried several different approaches to the problem with no success.

When I simply have the code `line.Cells[5].Value = vo2.Rows[0]["Start"].toString();` I get `3/9/2019 8:00:00` as the result in the `datagridview`.  I want this to be `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

How can I achieve this?

```
SmartsheetDataAdapter dataAdapter4 = new SmartsheetDataAdapter(sql10, connection);
 DataTable vo2 = new DataTable();
 dataAdapter4.Fill(vo2);
 //double vocost = 0;

 if (vo2.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     DateTime thisdate = new DateTime(vo2.Rows[0]["Start"]);
     //DateTime deldate = DateTime.ParseExact(dd1, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     line.Cells[5].Value = thisdate.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

Current code gives an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'long'

Comment: `DateTime thisdate = Convert.ToDateTime(vo2.Rows[0]["Start"]);`

Comment: @R.Rusev: `mm` means *minutes*, not *months*

Comment: Why is your date value stored as a `long`?

Comment: @silkfire date value is not `long`, it's `vo2.Rows[0]["Start"]` is `object` and it's triggering `DateTime(long ticks)` constructor (cause it's only constructor with 1 parameter).

Comment: @SeM Great thanks, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because the [`DateTime` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_) takes a long but you pass an object:

```
DateTime thisdate = new DateTime(vo2.Rows[0]["Start"]);
```

I guess that the first column in the `DataTable` is  already a`DateTime`, then use this:

```
DateTime thisdate = vo2.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Start");
```

Otherwise you have to parse it, for example:

```
string dtVal = vo2.Rows[0]["Start"].ToString(); // 3/9/2019 8:00:00
DateTime thisdate = DateTime.ParseExact(dtVal, "d'/'M'/'yyyy h:mm:ss", null);
```

or even simpler, because with this input you don't need `ParseExact` but you can use `Parse`:

```
DateTime thisdate = DateTime.Parse(dtVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `Convert` the value read (note, that `vo2.Rows[0]["Start"]` is of type `object` when you want `DateTime`):

```
 DateTime thisdate = Convert.ToDateTime(vo2.Rows[0]["Start"]);

 // MM - if you want leading zero; note, that "mm" stands for minutes
 line.Cells[5].Value = thisdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

**Explanation** of what's going on:

1. `vo2.Rows[0]["Start"` is of type `object`
2. `new DateTime(long ticks)` wants single `long` argument
3. The compiler complains of the argument's *type* given (if you call the constructor with *one* it must be of type `long`)